# Getting values from column B that do not have a corresponding value in column A

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with two columns in MSSQL.

column `id1` and column `id2` with any relation .

Example data:

```
id1   id2
12    13
13    14 
12    14 
13    15
```

Here 12 in `id1` is has relation with 13 in `id2`,
here 13 in `id1` is has relation with 14 in `id2`
such way..

How can I write an SQL Query so that when I pass `12`, I get the value(s) from column `id2` who does not have any relation with `12`?

(In this case, the answer would be 15)

Comment: You need something working recursivly, right?

Comment: @niktrs - if the OP wanted recursive, then I don't see how 15 is an answer (since (12,13) and (13,15) are in the set)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery in the where clause.

```
SELECT id2 FROM `test1`  
WHERE id2 NOT IN (SELECT id2 FROM `test1` WHERE id1 = 12)
```

Comment: fyi, this isn't SQL Server syntax

Answer (score 1):

If you any NULLs in id2, then NOT IN will *always* fail

You have to use EXISTS or EXCEPT for consistency and correct results

```
SELECT tr.id2
FROM MyTable tr
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTable tl
    WHERE tl.id1 = 12 AND tl.id2 = tr.id2)
```

Or

```
SELECT id2
FROM MyTable
EXCEPT
SELECT id2
FROM MyTable
WHERE id1 = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's as simple as:

```
select distinct id2 
from table 
where id2 not in (select id2 from table where id1 = 12)
```

I.e. you want to find all `id2` values, such that no row with that `id2` value has an `id1` of 12